# VS2010 Bug When Passing 64 bit enum to Printf

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, enums, compiler-bug

Some weird result encountered in VC++2010:

```
enum dow :unsigned long long {mon=0x800022223333ULL,tue};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    dow a=mon;
    unsigned long long b=0x800022223333ULL;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("%llx\n",a); // a is 32bit or 64 bit???
    printf("%llx\n",(unsigned long long)a);
    printf("%llx\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

I got some unexpected result:

```
8
1ff1d3f622223333
800022223333
800022223333
```

The  `1ff1d3f622223333` is incorrect. After inspecting the generated assembly code, I found that the compiler was passing a 32bit 0x22223333 in the printf for `a` which was then incorrectly interpreted as 64bit by the printf format specification. Hence the garbage `1ff1d3f6` was inserted. Why is it so?

EDIT
forgot to say that it was compiled as a 32bit exe with both Release and Debug Configuration.

Comment: VS2015 produces the same output in all three cases.

Comment: then very likely a bug with VC++2010

Comment: AlexD, did you compile the code as 32bit exe in VS2015?

Comment: Yes, both 32 and 64 in both Debug and Release configurations.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in that version of Visual Studio. The following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

enum dow :unsigned long long {mon=0x800022223333ULL,tue};
int main()
{
    dow a=mon;
    unsigned long long b=0x800022223333ULL;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("%llx\n",a); // a is 32bit or 64 bit???
    printf("%llx\n",(unsigned long long)a);
    printf("%llx\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

produces a similar result in VS2010:

```
8
22223333
800022223333
800022223333
```

However, it looks like it's been fixed in later releases, the same code run in VS2015 Express gives:

```
8
800022223333
800022223333
800022223333
```

Since our version of VS2010 has all patches installed, it looks like this was never fixed in that version. My suggestion therefore (if you really *need* those large enumerations) is to upgrade.